# Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to set up Kotlin Multiplatform Library in my android existing application, but getting the following error:

> Build file '/Users/tomtharakan/Documents/Projects/android/MyApplication/kmmsharedmodule/build.gradle.kts' line: 1
> Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Gragle Config:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    //iosSimulatorArm64() sure all ios dependencies support this target

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        framework {
            baseName = "kmmsharedmodule"
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        //val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            //iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        //val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            //iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 30
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 30
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a root `MyApplication/build.gradle.kts` with kotlin-gradle-plugins declaration? If it is not there or its missing required repositories, that might be the problem's cause.